# Thread-safety with C++ and passing by reference

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I wanted to confirm my understanding of threads and passing by reference in C++. Is the following function thread safe?

```
QString sA = "hello";
QString sB = "world";
bool someFlag = AreStringsEqual(sA,sB);

...

bool AreStringsEqual(QString const &stringA, QString const &stringB)
{
    if(stringA == stringB)
    {   return true;   }

    return false;
}
```

I think it *is* thread safe. I'd like it if someone could confirm my thought process, or tell me I have no idea what I'm talking about :)

- There are two copies of sA and sB in the process's memory. One set is created on Thread1's stack and the second set is created on Thread2's stack. Because we passed by reference, each thread only needs one set of sA and sB in memory to execute the function call.
- If we had passed by value instead, there could be up to four copies of sA and sB in the process's memory (each thread having two sets) at some time point where both threads were trading processor control within the function call.
- In no case is memory shared here, therefore the function is thread safe.

Sorry if this question is super simple, threads have fried my brain :)

Pris

Comment: What is QString? Does it implement an "==" operator? If so, then another thread could change either stringA or stringB during the execution of the == operator, potentially making it not thread safe.

Comment: I don't see threads in the code posted. Are `sA`, `sB` and `someFlag` globals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague on where `sA` and `sB` are declared. It sounds like they are declared inside a function, in which case you're correct that each thread would have it's own version of `sA` and `sB`. But, in the odd chance that they are declared at global scope, this is not the case. If I understand your question correctly, you meant that the two were declared at local scope, so your first point is correct. By the same token, your second point is correct as well.

Your third point is tricky, though. In your particular case, no memory is shared, so your program is a "thread-safe" program (not sure if that's a good way to word it). However, the function `AreStringsEqual` is *not* thread-safe. At some point in the future, you (or someone else) could use the function with data that *is* shared, and the function itself does not guard itself against this usage.

Comment: Even if they are declared in local scope, they are passed by reference, meaning that the memory locations are accessible to other functions (and threads) as well.

Comment: @IlyaKogan: I'm not sure I understand your point. If your talking about my first paragraph, that simply addresses how he count the copies of `sA` and `sB` throughout his program, which he is correct about. The issue of thread safety is addressed in my second paragraph, which I believe is correct also. In any case, the fact that `AreStringsEqual` uses pass-by-reference does not inherently give other threads or functions access to `sA` and `sB` (at least, not in his implementation). Could you clarify your point?

Comment: If I call `AreStringsEqual(a, b)` and then launch another thread that changes the contents of a and b, then this method will be vulnerable. Therefore it is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Ilya: That's what I said: "`AreStringsEqual` is *not* thread-safe".

Comment: The comments/discussion for this question really helped me out. Thanks guys! And yes, I should have clarified that sA and sB are not declared in a global scope.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason why two threads wouldn't hold references to the same strings.

This function is **not** thread-safe because the statement `if(stringA == stringB)` is not atomic. 
First you fetch `stringA` from memory, and only then `string B`.

Let's stay `stringA == stringB == 2`.

You fetch `stringA`, then there's a context switch and both stringA and stringB change to 3. Then you fetch `stringB`. Your function would return false (because `2 != 3`) although `stringA` was equal to `stringB` all along.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `QString` has specified that `operator==` *is* thread safe, the function is *not* thread safe. The implementation of `AreStringsEqual` does nothing itself to protect the data.

You are putting the responsibility of thread safety on the client with this implementation. The client must ensure the parameters and the parameters' internal data does not mutate (e.g. by another thread) while in `AreStringsEqual`. Consequently, they may find themselves making unnecessary copies. How exactly this must happen is dictated by the implementation of `QString`. Even `std::string` implementations vary dramatically =)

For strings in concurrent contexts, one would generally take a copy before moving the string into a concurrent context. If it really needs to be shared, you'll need something to protect it (such as a lock). For primitive collections (e.g. `std::string` and `std::vector`), you'll want to avoid locking at every access because it would kill performance and could fail rather easily. So, you'd generally copy or lock if you must share objects which are not explicitly thread safe.

Therefore, the implementation of `AreStringsEqual` is not thread safe (again, unless `bool QString::operator==(const QString&) const` is guaranteed to be thread safe).

However, your *usage* of `AreStringsEqual`:

```
QString sA = "hello";
QString sB = "world";
bool someFlag = AreStringsEqual(sA,sB);
```

would be fine for the majority of string implementations, because the parameters and their data would be local to the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not thread safe if sA and sB are shared between threads.

It is quite possible that during the execution of function AreStringsEqual in one thread, another thread tries to modify the value of sA or sB or both, then there would be a Race condition.

While your function is not modifying the value, code outside your function can.

So it is better to use pass by value, as then the function will have local copies on the stack
which is guaranteed to be thread safe

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not clear as to why you would need two copies of the same string if they are always to have equal value.

Perhaps it's thread safe based on the context you described, but simply looking at the function it self, it's not Thread Safe, since by the time the if condition is executed, values of the strings may have changed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code in the question is for example purposes only. At any rate, it's fairly common to compare two strings, and this is not the reason the function is not thread-safe.